"GET /static/assets/css/plugins/something.css.map HTTP/1.1" 404
I am getting this error every time I reload my website. And for this error it's taking so much time to reload the website. but my stylings from .css and .js are working.
I am getting this errors in my terminal -
[22/Oct/2024 03:51:18] "GET /static/assets/css/demos/demo-6.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[22/Oct/2024 03:51:18] "GET /static/assets/css/custom-old.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
**[22/Oct/2024 03:51:20] "GET /static/assets/css/plugins/jquery.countdown.css.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1989
[22/Oct/2024 03:51:20] "GET /static/assets/css/plugins/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css.map 
HTTP/1.1" 404 2028
[22/Oct/2024 03:51:20] "GET /static/assets/css/style.css.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1932
[22/Oct/2024 03:51:20] "GET /static/assets/css/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css.map HTTP/1.1" 404 2016
[22/Oct/2024 03:51:20] "GET /static/assets/css/demos/demo-6.css.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1953
[22/Oct/2024 03:51:20] "GET /static/assets/css/skins/skin-demo-6.css.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1968
[22/Oct/2024 03:51:20] "GET /static/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1956
[22/Oct/2024 03:51:20] "GET /static/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1971
[22/Oct/2024 03:51:20] "GET /static/assets/js/jquery.plugin.min.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1953
[22/Oct/2024 03:51:20] "GET /static/assets/js/jquery.countdown.min.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1962**

I am using soome jquery plugins. Here's i am linking the files in my base.html
CSS -
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/style.css'%}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/skins/skin-demo-6.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/demos/demo-6.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/fancy/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/custom-old.css'%}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/custom.css'%}">

JAVASCRIPTS -
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.elevateZoom.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.plugin.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.countdown.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.countTo.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.sticky-kit.min.js' %}"></script>

Thats some code from settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

I think there's an issue with mapping the css and js files. I have this one line of code in my every css and js files -
/*# sourceMappingURL=fileName.css.map */

But i don't have any .map files in that directory.
How can i solve this issue? It really stressing me out cause it taking too much time to load my site. Do you have any solves for this? Help me out Please.
